# EXC_BAD_ACCESS using QSort on an Array of Chars within Structs in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, exc-bad-access

I have searched through many of the answers on here and have implemented a few changes based on that, but am getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when calling the qsort function. My IDE is pointing to the return in my qsort compare function as the problem. I know I am allocating memory properly for all the elements as I can print the strings with no problem if I omit the call to qsort. Could someone point me in the right direction?

My structs, to see how deep I am navigating:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int siteId;
    unsigned int tableTypeId;
    unsigned int surMatId;
    unsigned int strucMatId;
    char *streetAve;
    unsigned int neighbourhoodId;
    char *neighbourhoodName;
    unsigned int ward;
    char *latitude;
    char *longitude;
} Entries;

typedef struct {
    int size;
    Entries **entry;
} PicnicTable;

typedef struct {
    Table *tableTypeTable;
    Table *surfaceMaterialTable;
    Table *structuralMaterialTable;
    NeighbourHoodTable *neighborhoodTable;
    PicnicTable *picnicTableTable;
} DataBase;

extern DataBase *DB;




Entries **ent = DB->picnicTableTable->entry;
qsort(ent,DB->picnicTableTable->size-1, sizeof(Entries*), cmpfunc); typedef struct {
    unsigned int siteId;
    unsigned int tableTypeId;
    unsigned int surMatId;
    unsigned int strucMatId;
    char *streetAve;
    unsigned int neighbourhoodId;
    char *neighbourhoodName;
    unsigned int ward;
    char *latitude;
    char *longitude;
} Entries;

typedef struct {
    int size;
    Entries **entry;
} PicnicTable;

typedef struct {
    Table *tableTypeTable;
    Table *surfaceMaterialTable;
    Table *structuralMaterialTable;
    NeighbourHoodTable *neighborhoodTable;
    PicnicTable *picnicTableTable;
} DataBase;

extern DataBase *DB;
```

This is what the call looks like:

```
Entries **ent = DB->picnicTableTable->entry;
qsort(ent,DB->picnicTableTable->size-1, sizeof(Entries*), cmpfunc);
```

And the compare function is:

```
int cmpfunc(const void *a, const void *b) { 
    Entries *left = *(Entries**)a;
    Entries *right = *(Entries**)b;

    return strcmp(left->neighbourhoodName, right->neighbourhoodName);
}
```

The picnicTableTable, and Entry are initialized after this malloc:

```
DB->picnicTableTable = malloc(sizeof(PicnicTable));
DB->picnicTableTable->entry = malloc(numEntries*sizeof(Entries)+1);
DB->picnicTableTable->size = numEntries;

while ((c=fgetc(IN)) != EOF) {
        if (c == ',' && row > 0) {
            switch (column) {
                case 0: neighbourhoodName = copyToChar(buff, begin, i);
...
}
```

copyToChar take a slice of the buffer and allocates memory then returns a pointer to a value that I assign:

```
char * copyToChar(const char * buff, int begin, int end) {
    char *temp = malloc(end - begin + 1);
    int j = 0;

    for (int i = begin; i < end; i++, j++)
        temp[j] = buff[i];
    temp[j] = '\0';

    return temp;
}
```

And the array is populated after I iterate through each row in a file (this is just one entry):

```
DB->picnicTableTable->entry[row]->neighbourhoodName = malloc(strlen(neighbourhoodName)*sizeof(char)+1);
```

The values of a->neighbourhoodName are NULL, which confuses me. Doesn't qsort pass two values from the array to the compare function?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The `qsort` passes pointers to the elements in the array it is sorting, and if the elements in the array are pointers it will be pointers to pointers.

Comment: ok, so that's not it. I still think that a typedef for `Entries *` would make that code clearer.

Comment: When in the debugger, having caught the crash in action, what is the value of `a` and `b`? Do they look valid? What about `(Entries **) a` and `(Entries **) b`? How about the `neighbourhoodName` members?

Comment: Also, how do you initialize `DB`? How do you initialize `DB->picnicTableTable`? How do you initialize `DB->picnicTableTable->entry`? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware. You declare entry to be a pointer to pointers (pointing to first element of an array of pointers)

```
typedef struct {
    int size;
    Entries **entry;
} PicnicTable;
```

but initialize it as a mere dynamic array, that is a pointer  to first element of an array of `Entrys` in:

```
DB->picnicTableTable->entry = malloc(numEntries*sizeof(Entries)+1);
```

If you want an array of pointers to speed up qsort, you should build it separately:

```
typedef struct {
    int size;
    Entries *entry;
    Entries **pentry;
} PicnicTable;

DB->picnicTableTable->entry = malloc(numEntries*sizeof(Entries)+1);
DB->picnicTableTable->pentry = malloc(numEntries*sizeof(&Entries)+1);
for (int i=0; i<=numEntries; i++) { // initialize the array of pointers
    pentry[i] = entry + i;
}
```

Currently the definition of `cmpfunc` is not coherent with your initialization of `DB->picnicTableTable->entry`.

Comment: Why not explicitly say that this allocation: `DB->picnicTableTable->entry = malloc(numEntries*sizeof(Entries)+1);` makes no sense, is wrong?

Comment: @alk: because my English did not allow me to find better words :-( . More seriously, I honestly thought that saying that one was an array of structs and the other an array of pointers to struct was enough. And I was trying to give OP a hint instead of just saying *that's wrong*, which he should already have understood since his program does not give expected results.

Comment: My comment was not meant offensive in any way, even more I appreciate respectful people. :-)

Comment: Thank you @SergeBallesta for the hints which did lead me in the right direction.